# Comparing two arrays in swift and removing elements with specific fields that don't match

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var packages = [SAPackage]()
var inappProducts = [SKProduct]()
```

The SAPackage object in the packages array has a String var titled sku. TheSKProduct object in the inappProducts array has a String var titled productIdentifier. What I want to do is remove any object in the packages array that doesn't have a sku String that matches any objects productIdentifier String in the inappProducts array. Is there anyway to go about this? Thought about using sets to find an intersection however I cannot examine individual object fields doing this just whole objects. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this code to filter those packages whose "sku" exist in inappProducts, SKProducts,

```
let filteredPackages = packages.filter { package in
    return inappProducts.contains { product in
        product.productIdentifier == package.sku
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Was trying something along these lines but couldn't get it right. thanks!

Comment: In my case I had to remove those matching elements so I just had to use "not contains", this solution also increased the performance compared to nested for loop, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter function of Swift.
Here a simple example:

```
let dic1 = ["bear","cat","dog","fish"]
let dic2 = ["horse","cat","dog","bird"]

let f = dic1.filter{dic2.contains($0)}

// ["cat", "dog"]
```